# Need help converting json to a particular format

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help with converting my json to an exact format, Ive tried the following below

```
var WhConns = [{"ConnectTo":"WormID2","UID":"WormID7","Cmass":"'#0000FF'","Cmass1":"'#0000FF|4'"},{"ConnectTo":"WormID7","UID":"WormID8","Cmass":"'#0000FF'","Cmass1":"'#0000FF|4'"},{"ConnectTo":"WormID8","UID":"WormID9","Cmass":"'#0000FF'","Cmass1":"'#0000FF|4'"}];


for (var i=0; i<WhConns.length; i++) {
 r.connection(WhConns[i].ConnectTo, WhConns[i].UID, WhConns[i].Cmass, WhConns[i].Cmass1);
}
```

but it doesnt work and iam not sure how to output it as below.

```
 r.connection(WormID7, WormID8, '#0000FF', '#0000FF|4');
```

If i put it out as document.write it will show the values, but Iam sort of at a dead end, so any help would be greatly appreciate and why it isnt working as above - so I can learn the errors of my way.

Comment: Have you tried `r.connection.apply(r, WhConns[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is working but not sure what is going wrong here. It is because you want exactly like this

```
r.connection(WormID7, WormID8, '#0000FF', '#0000FF|4');
```

and you do not want this

```
r.connection('WormID7', 'WormID8', '#0000FF', '#0000FF|4');
```

Is it what you want?

If so why dont you try

```
 for (var i=0; i<WhConns.length; i++) 
{ 
r.connection(parseInt(WhConns[i].ConnectTo), parseInt(WhConns[i].UID), WhConns[i].Cmass, WhConns[i].Cmass1); 
}
```

Comment: Exactly!!!! Just some more background info its useing the Raphaël library - graffle to link the conenctions. The method Iam using wants it exactly in this format.

Comment: `r.connection(WormID7, WormID8, '#0000FF', '#0000FF|4');` So how Do i go about getting it exactly like this?

Comment: if so why dont you try for (var i=0; i<WhConns.length; i++) {
 r.connection(document.write(WhConns[i].ConnectTo), document.write(WhConns[i].UID), WhConns[i].Cmass, WhConns[i].Cmass1);
}

Comment: the document write will ouput the values to screen, but it doesnt pass the values to the raphael function to draw the lines which it needs to

Comment: Because WormID7 is a string and you do not want a single quote around it so it has to be a number and you can try parseInt() and see how it goes.I do no know much about Raphael but as far as I can see the parameters passing in are numbers and colors not sure why you pass WormID7?